# JQuery Count number of classes where data attribute does not equal a certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of code that loops through to create rows as follows

```
<div class='link' data-job_id='123456'>
    <div class='holder'>
        <img class=q1 src='first_image.jpg' data-status='1' data-image='1' alt='first_image' />
        <img class=q1 src='second_image.jpg' data-status='4' data-image='2' alt='second_image' />
    </div>//end holder
</div>//end link
<div class='link' data-job_id='456789'>
    <div class='holder'>
        <img class=q1 src='first_image.jpg' data-status='2' data-image='1' alt='first_image' />
        <img class=q1 src='second_image.jpg' data-status='7' data-image='2' alt='second_image' />
    </div>//end holder
</div>//end link
....etc (this has been greatly simplified)
```

What I am having problems doing is counting the number of `link` classes where the `data-status` does not equal 4 and `data-image` value is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var links = $('.link q1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('status') != '4' && $(this).data('image') == '2';
}).length;
```